# How to add two random numbers within a range?

Tags: java, random, addition

My requirement :--

```
The sum of the two random numbers will be 100..
      sum=random_no1 + random_no2  (the sum will be exact 100)
```

So,I have tried:--

```
Random r = new Random();
        int Low = 10;
        int High = 100;
        int R = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    Random r1 = new Random();
    int Low1 = 10;
    int High1 = 100;
    int R1 = r1.nextInt(High1-Low1) + Low1;
```

but how I define the sum??

I can not understand..Please help me..

Comment: what do you mean by "how I define sum"? It's not clear.

Comment: Pick 1 random number. Then do 100-that number. That will be your second random number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, based on your requirements I'd suggest you just subtract your first random number from 100. Then you have two random numbers with that sum. Finally, Java naming convention is lower case letter first. Like,

```
Random r = new Random();
int low = 10;
int high = 100;
int r1 = r.nextInt(high - low) + low;
int r2 = 100 - r1; // <-- so that r1 + r2 is 100
```

Answer (score -2):

```
max =100;
min = 10;

FirstOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;

secondOne = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-FirstOne));

sum = FirstOne+secondOne;
```

Comment: Are you sure that it will results sum to `100`?

Comment: Math.random() doesn't accept any arguments, it returns a double between [0, 1). http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html